# Difference between service registry and discovery

Tags: apache-zookeeper, microservices, apache-curator

Like to know the difference between Service Registry and Discovery in Zookeeper in terms of Microsesrvices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is not specific to Zookeeper so these principles apply to every implementation (Eureka, Consul, Zookeeper, etc...)

Service registry is the registry where all services register themselves, giving a way to contact them (public API, IP, port).

Service Discovery is the action of retrieving a specific service for your need, basically asking the service registry to get an URL to call.